# Not able to store a Object in Joomla session

Tags: joomla-3.4, session

I am trying to store an object in Joomla session and it gets reset when I null the temp variable.

```
$whoami = new stdClass();
$whoami->type = 's'; $whoami->id = '1';

//Loading the value to session
$session->set('whoami',$whoami);

//Getting the session value to a temp variable
$temp = $session->get('whoami');
print_r($temp); //This prints correct as [type] => s [id] => 1
var_dump($temp);    

//Set the temp id to null
$temp->id = null;

//Again get the value from session
$test1 = $session->get('whoami');
print_r($test1);  // [type] => s [id] => 
var_dump($test1);
```

`var_dump` of `$temp` and `$test1` is as below

**$temp**

```
object(stdClass)#193 (2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "s"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

**$test1**

```
object(stdClass)#193 (2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "s"
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Assigning null to the temp id reset the value in the session variable... looks wierd...

Can someone please help.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump to make sure that `$temp` and `$test1` are the same objects. It definitely looks weird, because object manipulation outside the session could not influence on this object in session.

Comment: @DmitryRekun Added the `var_dump` output in the question.  Both the variables share the same resource number `193`

Comment: That's really odd :( I hope someone else will have an idea what is going on here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, your var $temp is a reference of the session object. So if you change the content of the object you change the session object itself.

You have to clone the object:

```
$temp = clone $session->get('whoami');
```

or you create a new object:

```
$temp = new stdClass();
$temp->type = $session->get('whoami')->type;
$temp->id = $session->get('whoami')->id;
```

Your var dump should look like this now:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => s
    [id] => 1
)
object(stdClass)#42 (2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "s"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
1stdClass Object
(
    [type] => s
    [id] => 1
)
object(stdClass)#812 (2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "s"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Further information:

[PHP Manual Object References](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.references.php)

[PHP Manual Object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)